# Google Cloud IAM User doesn't Inherit Role from Organization

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

There is User A under organization with role

- Kubernetes Engine Admin
- Editor
- Organization Role Viewer
- Project IAM Admin

There is project A under the organization.

However, User A does not appear under IAM of project A, when try `gcloud projects get-iam-policy projectA --filter bindings.members:[User A Email]`, it will return 0 matches, because there is NO User A email in IAM of project A.

Isn't User A automatically inherited from the organization, and gets corresponding of any projects under?

Comment: Add User A to the project. Then you will see the inherited roles.

Answer (score 2):

The role granted at the **Organization** level will be inherited by the **Folder** and **Project** levels.
You should add the user to a Project though, and that will solve it.

If you want to find out more about the IAM policies refer to [Using resource hierarchy for access control](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/resource-hierarchy-access-control)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any roles you assign to a user at the org level will be inherited by all the folders and projects within the org. So user A does have all the roles you listed on all the projects.

However,

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy projectA
```

(corresponds to [projects.getIamPolicy](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/getIamPolicy)) only returns the policies you set on projectA directly through

```
gcloud projects set-iam-policy projectA
```

(corresponds to [projects.setIamPolicy](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/setIamPolicy)).

It won't return the inherited policies from the org.

You should be able to find userA in the org IAM policy through

```
gcloud organizations get-iam-policy 123
```

(assuming your org id is 123).